# jquery ui dialog closed unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I intend to implement interactive Cancel button dialog using jquery-ui. When the user click Cancel, it display pop up confirm dialog. When the user click yes, it will respond based on the response status. Here is how I implemented the code.

```
function refreshPage() {
window.location.reload(true);
}

$(function() {
setTimeout(refreshPage,30000);

var cancelJob = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hiddenCancelPopup').dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                var bookingJobNo = $('.cancelButton').attr("rel");
                var channel = $('.cancelButton').attr("channel");
                var deviceId = $('.cancelButton').attr("deviceId");
                if(readCookie("mbtx_session_id") == null) {
                    $(".invalidId").dialog({});
                    return;
                }
                jQuery.get('/rest/v2/booking/cancel/'+  bookingJobNo + "?channel=" + channel + "&deviceId=" + deviceId,  function(result) {
                    if(result.status == 501) {
                        $(".hiddenCancelledPopup").dialog({
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                "OK": function() {
                                    alert("OK");
                                    window.location.reload(true);
                                    //$( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(".hiddenFailedCancelPopup").dialog({
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                "OK": function() {
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
             },
            "No": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}

$(".cancelButton").on('click',cancelJob);

$("body").on({
    ajaxStart: function(cancelJob) {
        $(this).addClass("loading");
    },
    ajaxStop: function(cancelJob) {
        $(this).removeClass("loading");
        refreshPage();
    }
});
```

The problem with this implementation is that upon displaying `$(".hiddenCancelledPopup").dialog` , the dialog closed unexpectedly even before the user clicks `OK` button. It was shown for a short while before disappears.

I realize that `setTimeout(refreshPage,30000);` (which means refresh every 30 seconds) may cause the problem but I observed that the dialog closed much shorter before 30 seconds interval. Any ideas on how to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Add an alert to `refreshPage` to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having a glimpse at your code, I suspect the issue is when ajax call stops i.e. in the following section of your code.

```
$("body").on({

    ajaxStart: function(cancelJob) {
        $(this).addClass("loading");
    },
    ajaxStop: function(cancelJob) {
        $(this).removeClass("loading");
        refreshPage();    //page refreshes after any ajax call stops after executing.
    }

});
```

Quite possibly, when UI dialog with class `hiddenCancelledPopup` appears the code inside `ajaxStop` function executes and it refreshes the page as you have called `refreshPage()` inside it, so your popup disappears before any user interaction.

I don't know your requirement but my advice would be to call `refreshPage()` at some other place if possible. Let me know how did it go.